# Setting custom column names for foreign Keys in Sequelize Node.js

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

`sequelize` noobie here so sorry in advance. I am making some Table associations in my app between `users` `posts` and `comments`

**Comments Model**

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';


export const comment = (db) => {
  db.define('comment', {
    commentContent: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
}
```

```
export const setModelRelationships = (db) => {
    const { user, post, comment } = db.models

    user.hasMany(post);
    user.hasMany(comment);

    post.belongsTo(user);
    post.hasMany(comment);

    comment.belongsTo(post);
    comment.belongsTo(user);
}
```

Checking my db `comments` has 6 columns:

id | commentContent | createdAt | updatedAt | postId | userId |

if I want to give the `postId` a custom name such as: `commentedOnPostId` how can I do this with Sequelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreignKey` option in associations like this:

```js
post.hasMany(comment, { foreignKey: 'commentedOnPostId' });
comment.belongsTo(post, { foreignKey: 'commentedOnPostId' });
```

It's important to indicate the same `foreignKey` option value in both associations.